# Comparing three lists to filter out common elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, if-statement

I am new to python and am currently practicing.
The practice question: provide Alice the function affair_meet that takes Bob, Alice and Silvester daily path in Paris, and returns a set of all places where Alice and Silvester can meet and be sure Bob won't be. I have managed to do the code below, however, I am unsure how to filter out bobs movement, can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
def affair_meet(bob, alice, silvester):
    
    list1 = []
    
    for x in alice:
        
        for c in bob:
            
            for i in silvester:
                
                if x == i and x !=c:
                    
                    if x not in list1:
                        
                        list1.append(x)
    
    return(list1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

     alice = ['Ⅱ', 'Ⅳ', 'Ⅱ', 'ⅩⅠⅩ', 'ⅩⅤ', 'Ⅳ', 'Ⅲ']
     bob = ['Ⅳ', 'Ⅲ', 'Ⅱ', 'ⅩⅩ', 'Ⅱ', 'ⅩⅩ']
     silv = ['ⅩVⅢ', 'ⅩⅠⅩ', 'Ⅲ', 'Ⅰ', 'Ⅲ', 'ⅩVⅢ']
     print(affair_meet(bob, alice, silvester)
```

This code will spit out ["XIX","III"]
Obviously, I want to get rid of the "III", since bob will also be there. Any hints?

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you iterate all combinations of `x`, `c` and `i`, meaning you will add a place to the result list if there is a match between Alice and Silvester, and if there is *any* place in Bob it does *not* match with.

Instead, just use a single loop over `alice` and use `in` to check the other lists. Since order does not really matter, use `set(alice)` to eliminate any duplicates, reducing another `if`-check.

```
def affair_meet(bob, alice, silvester):
    res = []
    for x in set(alice):
        if x in silvester and x not in bob:
            res.append(x)
    return res
```

You can make this shorter by using a list comprehension. Note that this is still O(n²) though, due to the O(n) membership tests in each iteration.

```
def affair_meet(bob, alice, silvester):
    return [x for x in set(alice) if x in silvester and x not in bob]
```

Or use basic set operations; this should also be faster as you convert `bob` and `silvester` to `set` just once and then have fast O(1) lookup. Convert back to `list` before `return` if you really need the result as a list.

```
def affair_meet(bob, alice, silvester):
    return set(alice) & set(silvester) - set(bob)
```

Comment: If you're going to use list comprehension imo there isn't a need to convert `alice` to a `set` and create extra overhead even if the example uses small lists, the conversion is 0(N) which could hurt in prod when there isn't anything gained from what i can tell.  you also forgot the x not in list1 from op

`return [x for x in alice if x in silverster and x not in [bob, list1]]`

Comment: @Bobdabear The `set(alice)` is not to speed anything up but so that the `in list1` check is not necessary. With the list-comp, you could also make it a set-comp without converting to `set` first; that's what I had first, but I guess OP wants to return a list.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `for c in bob:`, you can just check it at the end as follow:

```
if x == i:
    if x not in list1:
        if x not in bob:
            list1.append(x)
```

Like this, you are sure that bob will not visit x.